# How to see HTTP request header by curl?

Tags: linux, http, curl

I can see HTTP header response by `curl -I` command.

Is there any option to see the HTTP request header sent?

```
curl -I www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Dec 2011 00:55:53 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `curl` man page:

```
   -v/--verbose
          Makes the fetching more verbose/talkative. Mostly useful for debugging. A line  starting
          with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that
          is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional  info  provided
          by curl.
```